# Asyncio.sleep causes script to End Immediately

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, python-asyncio

In my simple `asyncio` Python program below, `bar_loop` is supposed to run continuously with a 1 second delay between loops.

Things run as expected when we have simply

```
    async def bar_loop(self):
        while True:
            print('bar')
```

However, when we add a `asyncio.sleep(1)`, the loop will end instead of looping.

```
    async def bar_loop(self):
        while True:
            print('bar')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
```

Why does `asyncio.sleep()` cause `bar_loop` to exit immediately? How can we let it loop with a 1 sec delay?

**Full Example:**

```
import asyncio
from typing import Optional

class Foo:
    def __init__(self):
        self.bar_loop_task: Optional[asyncio.Task] = None
        
    async def start(self):
        self.bar_loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.bar_loop())

    async def stop(self):
        if self.bar_loop_task is not None:
            self.bar_loop_task.cancel()

    async def bar_loop(self):
        while True:
            print('bar')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        foo = Foo()
        asyncio.run(foo.start())
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        asyncio.run(foo.stop())
```

Using Python 3.9.5 on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This behavior has nothing to do with calling `asyncio.sleep`, but with the expected behavior of creating a task and doing nothing else.
Tasks will run in parallel in the the asyncio loop, while other code that uses just coroutine and await expressions can be thought as if run in a linear pattern - however, as the are "out of the way" of the - let's call it "visible path of execution", they also won't prevent that flow.

In this case, your program simply reaches the end of the `start` method, with nothing left being "awaited", the asyncio loop simply finishes its execution.

If you have no explicit code to run in parallel to `bar_loop`, just await for the task. Change your `start` method to read:

```
async def start(self):
    self.bar_loop_task = asyncio.create_task(self.bar_loop())
    try:
        await self.bar_loop_task
    except XXX:
        # handle excptions that might have taken place inside the task
```

Comment: It's the only answer on the internet I found on this issue. But I still don't understand it.
Heres my understanding - Calling `asyncio.run(foo.start())` adds a coroutine to event loop and starts the execution. Then `asyncio.create_task(self.bar_loop())` should create another task in the same loop. So now we have two things in loop. They have equal right to be executed. When first (start) finishes, why would that cause bar_loop to be cancelled? According to my knowledge there is no "parent" and "child" tasks, but they are both equal. Thanks if you can answer

Comment: Nice comment - I will improve the answer to address it. TLDR: asyncio.run != loop.run_forever: it does _return_ when the awaitable passed to `run` completes, and the loop is put in a "paused" state.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer was not enough for me, because it didn't explain WHY the observed behaviour happens.

It seems that when using `asyncio.run` all tasks are being cancelled after the main "entrypoint" coroutine finishes.

So this code:

```py
import asyncio
import time

task = None

async def _generate():
    print("Starting generation")
    for x in range(10):
        print("generating...")
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("it never gets printed")


async def main():
    print("executing main")
    global task
    task = asyncio.create_task(_generate())
    print(task)
    print("main executed")


asyncio.run(main(), debug=True)
print(task)
```

Prints:

```
<Task pending name='Task-2' coro=<_generate() running at /home/mateusz/PROJECTS/Project3 - PyTango/issue-current/how_does_it_work.py:6> created at /home/mateusz/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py:361>
main executed
Starting generation
generating...
<Task cancelled name='Task-2' coro=<_generate() done, defined at /home/mateusz/PROJECTS/Project3 - PyTango/issue-current/how_does_it_work.py:6> created at /home/mateusz/miniconda3/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py:361>
```

The reason why it happens is the implementation of `asyncio.run` which uses `loop.run_until_complete` under the surface. Looking at the implementation (file `asyncio/base_events.py`):

```py
def run_until_complete(self, future):
    # ...
    future.add_done_callback(_run_until_complete_cb)
    try:
        self.run_forever()
    # ...
   
def _run_until_complete_cb(fut):
    # ...
    futures._get_loop(fut).stop()
```

So it is clear that when "main" task finishes, all other get cancelled and the loop get stopped.